# Printing to screen after searching in the database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, database

I am new to asp.net and trying to do simple things first. Now i am trying to make a simple library database. In my scenario user enters the title that he needs to search and then clicks search button. Here is the screenshot of my simple user interface:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Pages_Search : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void bSearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchedItem = tSearchBox.Text;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\Users\\SUUSER\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Library\\LibWebSite\\App_Data\\LibDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";



    Int32 verify;
    string query1 = "";
    if (SearchBy.SelectedValue == "Search by title")
    {
        query1 = "Select count(*) from Items where Title='" + tSearchBox.Text + "'";
    }



}
}
```

My question is, my query finds the number of items with that title, but does not print each item to the screen. How can i print out the search results to the screen? I mean how can i show the search results in another web page? I appreciate any helps.

Thanks

Comment: simply add: `GridView1.Databind();` after you called the query

Comment: @DiederikEEn thanks, i did it and worked but one little question: It works only for searching by title. For example, what if i choose search by author from dropdown list and want to search by author name? Can i handle it in gridview?

Comment: That is because the query is searching for Title. You could add a auto-postback for the dropdown list. And for the author, Is it possible for you to add that in the same Query with a `OR` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
"Select Title,count(1) from Items where Title='" + tSearchBox.Text + "'";
```

Comment: Thanks, but what i actually wonder is that how to print out the search results to the screen?

Comment: What do you mean by print on screen? Means on your View Page?

Comment: Yes, i mean after searching, the found results will be shown in another page

Comment: Then for that you have to take result in dataset or data reader and then pass it to next form and display on table or wherever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Tutorials such as this should help:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8659/Mastering-ASP-NET-DataBinding